# Get SPN error when trying to join a machine to a domain

Tags: windows, domain, windows-server-2016, spn

I am trying to join a Windows Server 2016 VM called `BORON` to a domain which has a Windows 2012 R2 domain controller. The DC name is `SNOWDROP.DUCK.LOC` When I try to join I get this error:

```
The operation failed because SPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide.
```

!?

I tried to find out why with this command on the domain controller:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {serviceprincipalname -like "*boron*"} | select *

DistinguishedName  : CN=SNOWDROP,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=duck,DC=loc
DNSHostName        : snowdrop.duck.loc
Enabled            : True
Name               : SNOWDROP
ObjectClass        : computer
ObjectGUID         : 2b5d6206-707a-4f09-835b-2d8222474e4d
SamAccountName     : SNOWDROP$
SID                : S-1-5-21-1075642099-280362434-2919291742-1001
UserPrincipalName  : 
PropertyNames      : {DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name...}
AddedProperties    : {}
RemovedProperties  : {}
ModifiedProperties : {}
PropertyCount      : 9
```

I'm not sure what else to try, any ideas?

Comment: If you view the Attributes tab for SNOWDROP in AD Users and Computers, does it have BORON in one of the ServicePrincipalNames?

Comment: Is this VM a clone? If so, did you Sysprep it before deploying it? If not, you need to.

Comment: @GregAskew yes it did. I removed them and it worked, not sure how that got it in there... do you want to write as answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @MarkAllison: sure thing!

Comment: Another thing to note if this VM was cloned without Sysprep (which you didn't confirm or deny); If you use WSUS you're going to have issues with a duplicate SUSClientID on all of the machines that were cloned, which you'll need to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you view the Attributes tab for `SNOWDROP` in `AD` Users and Computers, remove `BORON` if it is present in one of the `ServicePrincipalNames`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because there was already a server in the "computers" list with this name.  Removed that computer from the "computers" list and was able to join the server to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the specific host from the "Computers" section on the left from the domain which is under AD users and computer.

Also, i had to replicate the ADC and RODC from sites and services to update all of them.